# Eclipse Hibernate configurations pane does not display new Table

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am currently writing an Eclipse Java application using the Hibernate plugin.

I've started out by creating a schema in MySQL workbench, and then using the Hibernate plugin to auto-generate .hbm files and POJO code.

Recently, I added a ***new*** table, and some extra columns in one of my existing tables.

I got the Hibernate Configurations Pane to refresh, and display the extra columns in the existing table, but I am missing the new table that I created!

(Incidentally, I successfully verified that the schema built properly under MySQL Workbench).

Does anyone know a quick method for getting Eclipse Hibernate to include the new Table in the Configurations pane?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I figured it out... not a problem with Hibernate at all.

The privileges set for the new table were not set up correctly in the MySQL schema - hence the Hibernate pane could not see the new table.

Thanks.